# How To Read Line Numbers x Through (x+y) From A Very Large File

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have a very large text file where each line must be parsed.
I want to read lines x though x+100000 and add each line into a List such that list.size <= 100000.
The list will then be returned to the calling method for processing then the calling method will ask for the next 100k lines beginning where it left off last time.

The code below is one version using a BufferedReader. I returns the first 100k lines fine, but in the next call, starting at line 100k+1, it starts slowing down at around row 150k, and around line 165k it results in an OutOfMemoryError. I looked around for a way to empty the buffer once it gets to the line where I want to begin adding to the list, but I couldn't find any info on that. I also tried to find a way to skip x number of rows, but I couldn't find anything on that.

```
public List<MyModel> retrieve(File inputFile, int startLine, String checksum) throws DaoException {

    List<MyModel> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))) {

          String line = null;
          int row = 0;
          int iteration = 0;

          try {
              while (((line = br.readLine()) != null) && iteration < MAX_ROWS) {
                  row++;
                  LOGGER.info("row: " + row + ", iteration: " + iteration);
                  if (row > startLine && iteration < MAX_ROWS) {
                      MyModel model = this.fileReader.populateMyModel(line);
                      model.setFileChecksum(checksum);
                      result.add(model);
                      iteration++;                    
                  }
                  if (iteration >= MAX_ROWS) {
                      break;
                  }
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {

              throw new FileReaderException("Failed to read line " + iteration + " of " + inputFile.getAbsolutePath(), e);
          }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
          throw new FileReaderException("Could not find file '" + inputFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'.", e1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
          throw new FileReaderException("Could not read file '" + inputFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'.", e1);
    }

        return result;
}
```

While trying to find out how to skip lines, I ran across the Java 8 Stream way of reading files and the code below is my attempt to deal with it that way. This one also works great on the first call, returning the first 100k lines. For the second call, where it begins with line 100k+1, it returns "java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed". Additionally, I ONLY want to read lines x thru x+100k then return, not cycle through all the lines of the file. I'm new to this Stream object, but it seems like using that should provide a solution.

```
public List<MyModel> retrieve(File inputFile, int startLine, String checksum) throws DaoException {
    List<MyModel> result = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(inputFile.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        lines.skip(startLine);
        lines
        .filter(line -> result.size() <= 100000)
        .forEach(line -> {
            result.add(this.fileReader.populateMyModel(line));
            if (result.size() % 10000 == 0) {
                LOGGER.info("result size: " + result.size());
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You should chain with `skip().filter(...)...` , skip return a new stream, and you can't reuse a consumed stream.

Comment: @holi-java - While that exception is mentioned in the text of my question, that link does not address how to read a specific set of line numbers from a file, which is what this question is about.

Comment: well, if you think it is resonable. I revert it.  Ideed, I'm the first up-voter of the answer before I marked yours as duplicated. and I just want to tell you there is full detailed answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
lines.skip(startLine)
```

you create a new stream, but you don't save a reference to it, so you lose the operation.

I suspect you want something like:

```
return lines.skip(startLine)
            .limit(100000)
            .map(fileReader::populateMyModel)
            .collect(toList());
```

Comment: I changed the code to follow your guidance, but I still get an OutOfMemoryError. Even when I reduced the line count to 10000`result = lines.skip(startLine)
            .limit(10000)
            .map(fileReader::populateImportShippingNetRecord)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: I ran the same fix on a co-workers computer and it worked fine. It still slowed down, but it never ran out of memory. I'll have to check my system now, but this does seem to be the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Reading 100000 lines and storing them would not use so much memory (unless each line is 1000s of characters long). The problem may be due to either very long lines or your populateImportShippingNetRecord method which you haven't shown. You can use a profiler to find out where the memory is being used.

Comment: As it turns out, it was a misplaced instantiation of an arraylist inside a loop.